# Using xcode 4 but targeting OSX Leopard (10.5) and above

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I was developing an application using xcode 4 to target snow leopard (10.6)
Now, nearly the end of the development, I've been asked to support 10.5+.

I have set the Mac OS deployment target to 10.5 and compiled.
The compiler (LLVM 2.0) and linker seems to be happy with the change
but I came across a feature I've used from NSWindow (isOnActiveSpace) which is states as AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6_AND_LATER

This I understand states that it won't work (throw exception?) in 10.5 but no warning were raised when building.

I currently don't have a leopard installation and it will take our QA some time to arrange a computer for that, so in your experience, what should I do next? how can I go over the code and make sure that all the APIs I've used are in fact safe for 10.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` to `1050` and see what symbols disappear. More info in [TN2064](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2064/_index.html).

Comment: From what I've read this macro is defined from the Base SDK which can only be set to 10.6 on Xcode 4.

Comment: The SDK (specifically, the header AvailabilityMacros.h) only defines it if you didn't define it yourself. You can set MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050 with any SDK.